# Improving time-check for this simple Swift function involving integer to double conversion and division

Tags: ios, swift

This simple-looking Swift function seems to be reported as taking between 250 and 300ms to type-check (compilation time). This makes it one of the slowest functions in my whole app codebase to type-check, even though it looks pretty simple.

```
let quotaUsed: Int
let quotaTotal: Int

func isFractionOfQuotaUsed(_ fraction: Double) -> Bool {
    let fractionUsed = Double(quotaUsed) / Double(quotaTotal)
    return fractionUsed >= fraction
}
```

I have tried specifying the type of `fractionUsed` and that didn't help.

The time is being reported by Xcode, best to do a clean and then a build to get the time.

OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = -Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=250 -Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=250

Comment: What are `quotaUsed` and `quotaTotal`?

Comment: Sorry, edited to show they are both Int properties.

Comment: Can you show what you're using to calculate the execution time of this method

Comment: It is compilation time not execution time. Xcode you can set a build setting to warn when functions take longer than specified time to type-check during compilation. Clean and then build with that setting.

OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = -Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=250 -Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=250

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it matter the compilation time?

Comment: It's more that I am confused why this simple function takes longer to type-check that anything else in the app's codebase. I want to get the compile-time down so wanted to reduce compile-time wherever possible.

Comment: How often do you use this function in your code?

Comment: Quite a few places.

Comment: I got exactly the same issue. After decomposing all my code by sigle operation lines, type-check time was 175ms a this single line : `let myDouble: Double = Double(myInt)` Did you find any workarround ?

Comment: @ClementM I haven't yet, just left it for now, but would like to work out why.

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code,

```
let quotaUsed = 10
let quotaTotal = 20

func isFractionOfQuotaUsed(_ fraction: Double) -> Bool {
    let fractionUsed = Double(quotaUsed) / Double(quotaTotal)
    return fractionUsed >= fraction
}

let t1 = Date()
isFractionOfQuotaUsed(0.5)
let t2 = Date()

let time = t2.timeIntervalSince(t1).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) * 1000
```

And it is taking not more than `12 ms` to execute.

Comment: It is compilation time not execution time. Build setting in Xcode, then clean and build. OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = -Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=250 -Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=250

Comment: Question is not about execution time but type-check time, that means compilation time.